# OpenPyXL: Data Validation - Dependent Drop Down List

Tags: python, excel, drop-down-menu, dropdown, openpyxl

I managed to create a drop down list:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Fruit,Vegetable"')
ws.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(ws["A1"])
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

What I need is another drop down list, that is depencent on the first one.
If A1 is set to "Fruit", it should give me the option "Apple,Orange,..." and "Eggplant,Tomato,..." for Vegetable.

I am looking for a hardcoded solution, that is not dependent on tables in a worksheet.
If that is not possible, an alternative solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: This is not doable because, as Excel will warn you, the list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column. If it is a delimited list, it cannot be dynamic. If it is a reference, these values have to be stored somewhere. It is not possible to put them into a defined name either. This leaves you with storing the values somewhere in the workbook.